# Express and WebSocket on same port

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I have a chat app that uses a nodejs server, the server is combo of express node rest server and a web socket server on same port. Here is the code:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app     = express(),
    http    = require("http"),
    bodyParser  = require("body-parser"),
    methodOverride = require("method-override"),
//  server  = http.createServer(app),
    mongoose    = require("mongoose");
    
const port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000;
app.set('port', port);
app.set('ipaddr', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());


//Import routes
const chatsRoutes = require('./routes/chats');
    
app.use('/chats/', chatsRoutes);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Ready!");
});
 
/** catch 404 and forward to error handler */
app.use('*', (req, res) => {
  return res.status(404).json({
    success: false,
    message: 'API endpoint doesnt exist'
  })
});


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/thorapps_eu_pokenetwork', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, () =>
    console.log('Connected to Mongo DB')
);


//
// Websocket
//

const WebSocket = require('ws');

let WSServer = WebSocket.Server;
let server = require('http').createServer();

let wss = new WSServer({
  server: server,
  perMessageDeflate: false
})
server.on('request', app);

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
 var req = ws.upgradeReq;
 ws.on('message', function(msg) {
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({
   type: 'server',
   //method: req.method,
   //headers: req.headers,
   body: msg
  }, null, '\t'));
 });
});

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log(`Combo server on 3000`);
});
```

The setup works perfectly.
The problem I'm having is mixing both services...
For example, when a user send a new message to the chat it goes to express server to register it to the database, but then I'll like to notify other users on that chat that are connected.... but how could I send websocket messages from express server.....

my routes code is :

```
// user send message to a chat
router.patch('/add_message/:chatId', async (req, res) => {
    var updatedRaid;
    
    try {
        const user = req.body.user;
        const chat = await Chats.findOne({_id:req.params.chatId});

        const messageObj = {
            username: req.body.user.username,
            data_time: new Date(), // "mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT"),     // "6 sep 2020 23:20",
            text: req.body.message,
        };

        chat.messages.push(messageObj);

        chat.save((err, chat_result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            }

            Chats.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: 
                        {
                            raid : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.raidId)
                        }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                      from: "raids",
                      localField: "raid",
                      foreignField: "_id",
                      as: "raid"
                    }
                  },
                  { $unwind: "$raid" },
                  {
                    $lookup: {
                      from: "users",
                      localField: "raid.users.username",
                      foreignField: "username",
                      as: "users"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    $addFields: {
                      users: {
                        $map: {
                          input: "$users",
                          as: "t",
                          in: {
                            $mergeObjects: [
                              "$$t",
                              {
                                $first: {
                                  $filter: {
                                    input: "$raid.users",
                                      cond: {
                                        $eq: [
                                            "$$this.username",
                                            "$$t.username"
                                        ] 
                                      }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    $addFields: {
                      messages: {
                        $map: {
                          input: "$messages",
                          as: "m",
                          in: {
                            $mergeObjects: [
                              "$$m",
                              {
                                $first: {
                                  $filter: {
                                    input: "$users",
                                      cond: {
                                        $eq: [
                                            "$$this.username",
                                            "$$m.username"
                                        ] 
                                      }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  } 
                ]).exec((err, chat_resultant) => {

                if (err) throw err;
                
                res.json({
                    chatroom: chat_resultant[0],
                });
            })

            
          });
        
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({message: err.message});
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to switch all communication except authentication to WebSocket. Though you are able to pass your `wss` to route, it is much more easier and quickier manage all communication in WebSocket. REST API means, every single request is authenticated, when you use websocket for both direction, the application will be much responsible.

I have taken the approach with several Websocket routes, which replace REST API router.

Then:

```
...
wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {     
      ws.on('message', (m) => serverSubscriber(wss, ws, JSON.parse(m), req.user))
      });    


const serverSubscriber = (wss, ws, m, req.user) => {
    switch (m.route) {
        case 'newMessage':
            wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
                if (c.readyState === 1) {
                   client.send({
                       route: 'messageResponse',
                       data: 'hello'
                   })
                 }             ​
​...
```

So are you able to send and receive messages, both to one or all connected clients.

For authentication try `wss.handleUpgrade` from ws documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#client-authentication
Here you can pass your user information to WebSocket request, so your subscribers can work with it.

EDIT: After comment, another solution proposal:
For such cases I use internal WebSocket: simply create in your express route new WebSocket client, that will connect to your current websocket on localhost.

```
const internalSocketClient = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:1200/websocket/`);

router.get('/newmessage', (req, res) => {
    ... parse and do what you want ...
    internalSocketClient.send({route: 'internalMessage', data: req.body.message})
})
```

And your websocket server onMessage:

```
ws.on('message', (msg) => {
    if (JSON.parse(msg).route === 'internalMessage') {
        console.log('Message received from express path')
        // now emit the message to all clients
    }
    })
```

But I would still strongly recommend to rewrite the code - it is not so tough - I've done this in last days, switching from REST API to WS, the advantages are great.

Comment: yes, maybe switching to websocket is the best solution, if I knew it before. The problem is that I already have a lot of code using REST so now the change is very difficult...

Comment: See new answer proposal.

Comment: Thanks! I'll reconsider your advise

Comment: @MarcoMartin if you're still having this problem, I've posted a working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773285/defining-websocket-routes-for-express/69773286#69773286